VBA Loop Based on Branch Name List
Please help me out with LOOP function, as I want to save data in new excel file for every branch based on branch name (Branch_List) sheet. Need to split data & save file based on Branch list. below is the my code with 2 branch name. Attaching the branch name list for your referance.
Below is my code:
Sub Due_Sheet()

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\hp\Desktop\@ARMAN_MSME_MACRO\All Products Due List May'24.xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Due May-24").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Branch_List").Select
Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AMALNER SME"
Sheets("Due May-24").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AK$1000000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
    "AMALNER SME"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Columns.AutoFit
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AMALNER SME"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\@ARMAN_MSME_MACRO\AMALNER SME.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("Branch_List").Select
Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "BALAGHAT SME"
Sheets("Due May-24").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AK$1000000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
    "BALAGHAT SME"
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Columns.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
ChDir "C:\Users\hp\Desktop"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\hp\Desktop\@ARMAN_MSME_MACRO\BALAGHAT SME.xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWindow.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub


First immediate comment... avoid select.

Beyond a lot of the bad hygiene the one that'll get you is how explicitly things are defined. You're saying to make a cell a certain name and file should be a certain name, but really this should be constructed as variables so it's less programming and more dynamic. Consider making a table of all the dept names you want to run through, even if it's just two. Then say for every name in that list, change the cell to be that name (driving your formula) then save the file as generic name & Dept name, so you don't need to explicitly say it everytime and add to your code every time a dept changes.

Please share the screenshots of the worksheets. Why are you writing to Branch_List?

Because Branch_List is the sheet name from which I get Branch Name to split/save new data file.
